# Accessing an integer within a structure which has Pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to pointers and trying to use a pointer to the structure.I need to access the structure parameter using pointer. Kindly assist me.

Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct{
int a;
int b;
int c;
}time;

typedef struct{
int a;
int b;
time record;
}myarray;

typedef struct{
  myarray *ptrtoarray
}access;

myarray n_my_array_first[2] =
{

    {1 ,2 , {1 , 2 ,2}},
    {100 ,121 , {123,322,65535}}

};

myarray n_my_array_third[2] =
{
  {23,44,{1,43,22}},
  {23,48,{455,666,999}}
};

access n_access[5] =
{
       {&n_myarray_first},
       {((void *)0)},
       {((void *)0)},
       {&n_myarray_third},
       {((void *)0)}
};

int main()
{

   /* access the record.c parameter of second element of n_my_array_third array.
       whose value is 999 

  I have tried it as : 
   time v = n_access[3].(n_myarray_third + 1) -> record.c ; 
   But I am getting an error */


    return 0;
}
```

Q 1 )Explain what could possibly be done to access the fields .

Q 2 )Present any simpler ways to achieve the same thing (by using structure within structure)
if possible.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
time v = (n_access[3].ptrtoarray + 1)->record;
int c = v.c;
```

To avoid copying the `time` structure, use a pointer,

```
time *v = &(n_access[3].ptrtoarray + 1)->record;
int c = v->c;
```

Simpler way? Don't do it all in one line

```
access* my_access = &n_access[3];
myarray* array = &my_access->ptrtoarray[1];
time *v = &array->record;
int c = v->c;
```